# Accessing XAML elements from C# using string or arrays

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am new to WindowsApp Development and I was trying to access `XAML` elements through `C#` code using an array. 
For example I have few ellipses in my `XAML` code-

```
<Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5" x:Name="E_0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,5.849"  Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5" x:Name="E_1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,5.849"  Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5" x:Name="E_2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,5.849"  Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Now I want to work with them in `C#` in a loop so I am doing something similar to the following-

```
string s1="E_";
double width=500;
for (int i = 0; i < 2;i++ )
 {
    string name_i = s1 + i.ToString();
    name_i.Width = width / 2;
 }
```

But `name_i.width` gives me an error. So, do I have to use the actual names, is there no way I can use an array or string? Using the actual names will defeat the purpose as I have about 50 such elements which I need to work upon.

Comment: And if you'd group the `Ellipse` objects in a container and give that container a variable name, couldn't you loop through the `Children` of that container and affect every eclipse thereby?

Comment: Maybe, I am not sure, actually I do have all the `Ellipses` in a Grid by the name of `Game`. But if I enumerate the children, how can I check only for the `Ellipse` elements and not other elements present in that `Grid`?

Comment: You ask for the type of that child-control by doing a `if( someChild.GetType() == typeof(Ellipse))`. Otherwise, group all the ellipses into a staticly-accessible array (i.e. `var ellipses = {E_0, E_1, E_2, ...};`) then iterate over them.

Comment: Will that not require two loops- an outer loop iterating over `Children` and the inner loop iterating over my `var ellipses`. Is there some way, I can  do this using a single array instead of `Container` because if it is possible, the n I think it would be more efficient.

Comment: No, I meant you *either* group them in a container and iterate over the `Children`, or you group them in an array by code with the `Ellipse[] ellipses = { ... };` and iterate over this array, but not both at once.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Oh yes, got it. I think the second approach is much more efficient. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Just one more question using `Ellipse[] ellipses = { E_0, E_1, E_2 };` will suffice or do I need to do something else to access by name?

Comment: Since you've defined ` x:Name="E_0"` etc. in every eclipse you should have this variable name available, so that works and should compile. Eh, maybe with a `new Ellipse[]` before the `{` but I think that has become redundant with newer C# versions.

Answer (score 2):

As Maximillian proposed, you can use the parent container and iterate over its children:

Xaml:

```
 <StackPanel Name="StackPanelContainer">
      <Grid></Grid>
      <Ellipse Name="E_0"></Ellipse>
      <Ellipse Name="E_1"></Ellipse>
      <Ellipse Name="E_2"></Ellipse>
    </StackPanel>
```

Codebehind:

```
        //if you are sure every child element is a ellipse, you can use:
        foreach (Ellipse child in StackPanelContainer.Children)
        {
            child.Width = 100;
        }

        //if there are also other elements, and also check if name starts with "E_"
        foreach (object child in StackPanelContainer.Children)
        {
            var ellipse = child as Ellipse;
            if (ellipse != null && ellipse.Name.StartsWith("E_"))
            {
                ellipse.Width = 100;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but is there some other way to achieve this using arrays. This is because this will mostly not work if I want to work with just some of the Ellipses. Say I want to change Width of only some 15 out of 50 Ellipses, then comparing each of them with their name will involve two loops(if I am correct)-one outer loop iterating over the `Children` and the other loop which will iterate over my array where I will compare the names of the `Children`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `FindName()` method.

```
string s1 = "E_";
double width = 500;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    string name_i = s1 + i.ToString();

    var ellipse = FindName(name_i) as Ellipse;

    if (ellipse != null)
    {
        ellipse.Width = width / 2;
    }
}
```